# How to know when asp.net ajax request has completed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net web form with a button, label, scriptmanager and updatepanel controls. When I click the button, the label changes using ajax. How can I detect the change in the label using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**add_endRequest**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function endRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     alert("ended");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using ajax to change or update something on some event. If it changes naturally your output will be changed. If it is some kind of change that doesn't change output but change any attribute then
1. Install firebug addon
2.use it when firing your ajax function. 
3. On console mode you will see any change of error which you are expecting from the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use update progress for this purpose.
Here is a good example for update progress
http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/updateprogress.html